# Splitting arrays in RDD partitions in Pyspark

Tags: python, numpy, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a single file of 3D numerical data which I read from in chunks (since reading in chunks is faster than a single index). For example say there is an MxNx30 array in 'file', I would create an RDD like this:

```
def read(ind):
    f = customFileOpener(file)
    return f['data'][:,:,ind[0]:ind[-1]+1]

indices = [[0,9],[10,19],[20,29]]
rdd = sc.parallelize(indices,3).map(lambda v:read(v))
rdd.count()
```

So each of the 3 partitions has a numpy.ndarray element of size MxNx10.

Now, I would like to split each of these elements so in each partition, I have 10 elements, each element being an MxN array. I tried using flatMap() for this purpose, but get an error that 'NoneType object is not iterable':

```
def splitArr(arr):
    Nmid = arr.shape[-1]
    out = []
    for i in range(0,Nmid):
         out.append(arr[...,i])
    return out

rdd2 = rdd.flatMap(lambda v: splitArr(v))
rdd2.count()
```

What is the correct way to do this? The key points are (a) I need to read data in chunks from the file and (b) split the data so elements are size MxN (preferably keeping partition structure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand your description something like this should do the trick:

```
rdd.flatMap(lambda arr: (x for x in np.rollaxis(arr, 2)))
```

Or if you prefer a separate function:

```
def splitArr(arr):
    for x in np.rollaxis(arr, 2):
        yield x

rdd.flatMap(splitArr)
```

Comment: I see, I should have guessed from the Iterable error. Move the dimension to split on to the front of the array with rollaxis, then iterate over those elements. Just what I wanted, thanks a lot.